# Difference between de Broglie wavelength and electromagnetic wavelength

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

What is the difference between de Broglie wavelength and wavelength of electromagnetic radiation? Is there any relation between $\lambda=\dfrac{hc}{E}$ and $\lambda= \dfrac{h}{mv}$? (E stands for energy of electromagnetic radiation.)

Comment: Google De Broglie wavelength. Then you can ask questions on the parts you may not follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a relationship.  The base relationship is between an object's *momentum* and its de Broglie wavelength:
$$
\lambda = \frac{h}{p}.
$$
For a particle that is not moving at relativistic velocities ($v \ll c$), we have $p = mv$ and so the relationship becomes $\lambda = h/mv$.  However, for a photon, its momentum is not equal to $mv$;  instead $p = E/c$, where $E$ is the photon's energy.  If you plug this in to the above relationship, you obtain $\lambda = hc/E$.

You may be wondering why a photon has a different relationship between its momentum and its velocity than a conventional particle does.  That's probably a separate question, and one that I'm confident has been answered many times on this site;  I would encourage you to search this site for "photon momentum" for answers to this.